# Understanding pipe, fork and exec - C programming

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exec

I am trying to understand `pipe`, `fork` and `exec` in C, so I tried to write a little program that takes an input string and prints it out with the help of 2 child processes that run simultaneously.

**Since the code is too long I posted it in this link: https://pastebin.com/mNcRWkDg which I will use as a reference. I also posted the short version of my code at the bottom**

Example what should it do with input `abcd`:

```
> ./echo
abcd
result -> 
abcd
```

I am taking an input though `getline()` and checking if the `input_lengh` is even or can be broken into even parts. If it's just one `char` it just prints it out.

If it is for example `abcd` i.e has `input_length` of 4, it will split it into 2 parts `first_part` `ab` and `second_part` `cd` with the help of the `struct parts` like this:

```
struct parts p1; 
split(input, &p1);
```

Then I setup `pipe` for first child and `fork` it and then for the second child the same. I redirect first child `output` to be input of the parent process and the same for the second child. Let's assume that that part works like it should.

Then I write it to their child processes input:

```
write(pipeEndsFirstChild2[1], p1.first_half,  strlen(p1.first_half));
write(pipeEndsSecondChild2[1], p1.second_half,  strlen(p1.second_half));
```

After that I open their outputs with `fdopen()` and read it with `fgets()`

At the end I allocate memory and concat both results with:

```
char *result = malloc(strlen(readBufFirstChild) + strlen(readBufSecondChild));

strcat(result, readBufFirstChild);
strcat(result, readBufSecondChild);
```

I used `stderr` to see the output since `stdout` is redirected and what I get is:

```
>./echo 
abcd
result ->
cd
result ->
ab
result -> 
����
```

**Question:**
How do I get child process 1 to give me the `ab` first and then the second child to give me `cd` i.e how do I assure child processes run in correct order? Since I am only printing How do I save `ab` and `cd` between processes and concat them in the parent process to output them onto `stdout`?

If I try:

```
 >./echo
 ab    
 result ->
 ab
```

everything works as expected, so I guess if I have to call child processes multiple times as in `abcd` input then something gets messed up. Why?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int status = 0; 
char *input;
input = getLine();
int input_length = strlen(input);

if((input_length/2)%2 == 1 && input_length > 2)
{
    usage("input must have even length");
}

if (input_length == 1)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", input);
}else
{
    struct parts p1; 
    split(input, &p1);

    int pipeEndsFirstChild1[2];
    int pipeEndsFirstChild2[2];

    .
    .
    .
    pid_t pid1 = fork();
    redirectPipes(pid1, pipeEndsFirstChild1, pipeEndsFirstChild2);

    int pipeEndsSecondChild1[2];
    int pipeEndsSecondChild2[2];

    .
    .
    .
    pid_t pid2 = fork();
    redirectPipes(pid2, pipeEndsSecondChild1, pipeEndsSecondChild2);


    // write to 1st and 2nd child input
    write(pipeEndsFirstChild2[1], p1.first_half,  strlen(p1.first_half));
    write(pipeEndsSecondChild2[1], p1.second_half,  strlen(p1.second_half));

    .
    .
    .

    // open output fd of 1st child
    FILE *filePointer1 = fdopen(pipeEndsFirstChild1[0], "r");

    // put output into readBufFirstChild
    fgets(readBufFirstChild,sizeof(readBufFirstChild),filePointer1);

     // open output fd of 2nd child
    FILE *filePointer2 = fdopen(pipeEndsSecondChild1[0], "r");

    // open output fd of 2st child
    fgets(readBufSecondChild,sizeof(readBufSecondChild),filePointer2);

    //concat results
   char *result = malloc(strlen(readBufFirstChild) + 
   strlen(readBufSecondChild) + 1);
   strcpy(result, readBufFirstChild);
   strcat(result, readBufSecondChild);

    fprintf(stderr, "result ->\n%s\n", result);

    if(wait(&status) == -1){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please copy the relevant part of the code from the link. Some people cannot/would not want to access external links.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I added it at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Why do you need `buf` and `buf2`? You can write directly from `p1.first_half` and `p1.second_half`.

Comment: The child processes wiill run concurrently, but it doesn't matter. You're reading from the first child first, so you should get the results in the correct order.

Comment: @Barmar as I showed in my output above, I get cd first and then ab. That is not the correct order.

Comment: That output doesn't match the code you posted. Your program prints `result ->`, not `result:`. It also only prints the result once, not 3 different results.

Comment: @Barmar I just tried it again and it outputs the exact same thing I wrote in my question (I edited it to be result -> like in code) and it does print 3 different results. Can you tell me which input did you use?

Comment: I didn't run your program. I just don't see where you're printing the output of each process. There's only one `printf()` statement, and it prints the concatenated result.

Comment: @Barmar that's exaclty my question. How do I do it correctly. My problem is that it does print 3 different results and not in correct order

Comment: What program are you executing in the child processes? The child program is supposed to be the first argument to your program, but you're running it with no arguments. Could that extra output be coming from the children?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see it's `program_name = argv[0]`, so you're running the same program as the parent and children.

Comment: @Barmar yes, thats correct. I figured it that the child processes are giving the extra output and that I need to have `stdout` on my main parent process but I don't quite understand how to determine where should I put that.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to control the order that child processes run if they both have input available to them.

The way to solve this in your application is that you shouldn't write to the second child until after you've read the response from the first child.

```
write(pipeEndsFirstChild2[1], p1.first_half,  strlen(p1.first_half));
char readBufFirstChild[128];
FILE *filePointer1 = fdopen(pipeEndsFirstChild1[0], "r");
fgets(readBufFirstChild,sizeof(readBufFirstChild),filePointer1);

write(pipeEndsSecondChild2[1],  p1.second_half,  strlen(p1.second_half));
char readBufSecondChild[128];
FILE *filePointer2 = fdopen(pipeEndsSecondChild1[0], "r");
fgets(readBufSecondChild,sizeof(readBufSecondChild),filePointer2);
```

I've omitted the error checking and closing of all the unnecessary pipe ends.

You only need to do this because each process is printing its portion of the result to `stderr`, so you care what order they're running. Normally you shouldn't care about the order that they result, since they can contribute their portion of the final result in any order. If only the original parent process displayed the result, your code would be fine.

Comment: I edited my question and corrected the mistakes you pointed out, but this answer doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your main question.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but this doen't change my output. I will wait to see if somebody can help me get it as one complete output in correct order. Anyway I appreciate your help.

Comment: The program is actually hanging for me when I make these changes. The problem is that the second child inherits the pipes used to communicate with the first child, which is preventing the first child from getting EOF when the parent closes `pipeEndsSecondChild2[1]`